# Proving that the integral of one function is equal to the integral of another

Tags: real-analysis, integration

We have $f\in\mathcal{R}(\alpha)$, where $\mathcal{R}(\alpha)$ is the collection of all Riemann-Stieltjes integrable functions with respect to α. $g$ is a bounded function on $[a,b]$, and $Q=\{x\in[a,b]: f(x)\neq g(x)\}$.  Suppose $Q$ is finite and that $\alpha$ is continuous at every point of $Q$.  Prove that $g\in\mathcal{R}(\alpha)$ and that $\int_a^b fd\alpha=\int_a^b gd\alpha$.

I've proven the first part, that $g\in\mathcal{R}(\alpha)$ as follows:

We can write $g$ as $g=f-(f-g)$.  Since $f(x)-g(x)=0$ when $x\not\in Q$ (by definition of $Q$), we have that $f-g$ is a bounded function with finitely many discontinuities, which occur when $\alpha$ is continuous, as $\alpha$ is continuous in $Q$.  Thus, $(f-g)\in R(\alpha)$, and so since $f\in R(\alpha), (f-g)\in R(\alpha)$, we have that $g=f-(f-g)\in R(\alpha)$.

I'm having difficulty proving the second part.  Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can write the function $g-f$ as:

$g-f = 0 + t_{1} + ... + t_{n}$

In this case, the functions $t_{i}$ (let $n = |Q|$) are zero everywhere except at one single point $x_{i}$ (i.e. the points in where $f(x) \neq g(x)$). One can easily show that the integral of those functions $t_{i}$ will be $0$ (as the lower sums are always $0$, and these functions are integrable, so the integral will be $0$). Using linearity of the integral shows that the integral of $g-f$ is $0$ and therefore proves the main result.